# cant save data into mysql (page become blank after press save button)

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code.....
after i press the save button cant save my data into mysql
and that page became blank

```
<?php $nama_pengguna =$_GET['nama_pengguna']; ?>
<?php include('../Connections/connection_db.php'); ?>
<?php
$Nama = $_POST['Nama'];
$No_KP = $_POST['No_KP'];
$NoNDP = $_POST['NoNDP'];
$Semester = $_POST['Semester'];
$kursus = $_POST['kursus'];
$NoTelPelajar = $_POST['NoTelPelajar'];
$alamat_1 = $_POST['alamat_1'];
$alamat_2 = $_POST['alamat_2'];
$Poskod = $_POST['Poskod'];
$Bandar = $_POST['Bandar'];
$Negeri = $_POST['Negeri'];
$namabp = $_POST['namabp'];
$No_Tel_bp = $_POST['No_Tel_bp'];
$alamat_1_bp = $_POST['alamat_1_bp'];
$alamat_2_bp = $_POST['alamat_2_bp'];
$poskod_bp = $_POST['poskod_bp'];
$Bandar_bp = $_POST['Bandar_bp'];
$Negeri_bp = $_POST['Negeri_bp'];

$data =mysql_query ("INSERT INTO maklumat_pelajar (No_KP, Nama, No.NDP, Semester, Kursus, No_Tel_Pelajar, Alamat, Alamat_2, Poskod, Bandar, Negeri, Nama_BP, No_Tel_BP, Alamat_BP, Alamat_BP_2, Poskod_BP, Bandar_BP, Negeri_BP) VALUES ('".$_POST['No_KP']. "','".$_POST['Nama']. "','".$_POST['NoNDP']. "','".$_POST['Semester']. "','".$_POST['kursus']. "','".$_POST['NoTelPelajar']. "','".$_POST['alamat_1']. "','".$_POST['alamat_2']. "','".$_POST['Poskod']. "','".$_POST['Bandar']. "','".$_POST['Negeri']. "','".$_POST['namabp']. "','".$_POST['No_Tel_bp']. "','".$_POST['alamat_1_bp']. "','".$_POST['alamat_2_bp']. "','".$_POST['poskod_bp']. "','".$_POST['Bandar_bp']. "','".$_POST['Negeri_bp']. "')");

//$data = mysql_query($query);
echo $data;

//header ("location:../bppl/register_pelajar.php?nama_pengguna=$nama_pengguna");    
?>
```

can anyone got another way to do it?

Comment: You have error reporting on?

Comment: nothing error just nothing happen after press the button

Comment: What does `mysql_query()` return? Let me RTFM... It returns mixed so echoing will be empty of it returns false. Let me RTFM a bit more. Oh there's a `mysql_error()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that

```
  No.NDP
```

to

```
 `No.NDP`
```

in your columns

you should escape your variables first before inserting them by

```
  mysql_real_escape_string()
```

to see what error you have use mysql_error() like that

```
   $data =mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ...........")or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
              $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO maklumat_pelajar('$No_KP','$nama','$NoNDP',
'$smester','$kursus',
    '$NoTelPelajar','$alamat_1','$alamat_2','$Poskod','$Bandar','$Negeri',
    '$namabp','$No_Tel_bp','$alamat_1_bp','$alamat_2_bp','$poskod_bp',
    '$Bandar_bp','$Negeri_bp')");
    if(!$sql) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
```